# How to set datetime-local's input value using datetime data from SQLServer?

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, input

I was able to insert data to my sqlserver database using this:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($promostart));
```

So the value on my database is: `2021-08-10 23:59:00.000`

I tried echoing the value from my database directly to my input field like this: `<input type="datetime-local" id="dateStart" name="dateStart" value="<?php echo $row[DurationStart];">`

But the input field does not show both time and date specified in the value. and shows up like this: [image]

What should i do to be able to output/display it to my **datetime-local** input field?

Any clue or guide is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Select it and then echo it? It's a bit unclear where you're stuck, and the specifics of how you might do it could depend on the overall way your application is implemented (and the relationship between the data layer and the UI). We don't have any of that context. Please see [ask] and then clarify your post. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I added more information to my question, sorry about that. I already tried echoing the data into the datetime-local's value="" but the field still shows the placeholder instead of the one i echoed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to set the `datetime-local` **input value** using **date()** function:

```
$dateStart = $row['DurationStart'];
date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", strtotime($dateStart));
```